# Reduce the margins around R Markdown ggplotly plots on phone?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr, ggplotly

I'm trying to get ggplotly images to work correctly in my R Markdown files...on my phone (long story). Due to the elongated screen, the margins around the content are compressing the ggplotly HTML images so that the charts are illegible. How does one eliminate these margins altogether?

I've tried adding the following CSS to override the margins, to no avail (although it does help with aligning the left and right margins...):

```css
.main-container {
    max-width: 1800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I get the following output (I'm trying out dark modes):
Knitted HTML file on phone screen:
[image: Knitted HTML file on phone screen]

Has anybody else tried to get knitted reports on their phone? Any luck/tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - I was unable to fix the issue with margins, however by shifting the position of the legend and removing some of the plotly interactive buttons, I was able to make the graph more usable. In the end I shifted to Shiny (specifically the shinyMobile package) for a better UI though.